# Start shiny app in showcase mode below app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a `DESCRIPTION` file like this

```
Title: My app
Author: Jon Hill
AuthorUrl: https://ipardalis.com
DisplayMode: Showcase
Tags: R, Panther Chameleon, blog
Type: Shiny
```

When it starts, the code is shown alongside the app. However, I like the way it looks below the app after clicking "show below." Is there a way to get the app to start in that state instead of the default, which shows your app's code on the right side?

Here is a basic app for testing:

```
## app.R ##
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an elegant solution using Dean Attali's `shinyjs` package:

### ui.R

```
useShinyjs(),
```

### server.R

```
shinyjs::runjs('toggleCodePosition();')
```

Pretty straightforward once I inspected the button and found the js code it was running.